# Unity gone after upgrading 14.10 to latest 3.16 kernel

Tags: unity, kernel, 14.10

After upgrading 14.10 to the latest 3.16 kernel today, my Unity GUI is messed up. I was able to create a folder and open it, but if I navigate to the **/bin** folder, right-click on **bash**, then select **Run**, nothing happens. I can't start *any* program.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> doesn't work, but I can get to the terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>. (Thanks to @spqpad for pointing that out!)

I am running this as a VirtualBox 4.3.20 guest. I did have the Guest Extensions for 4.3.18 installed when I upgraded all my packages, including the kernel, with the intent of installing the new Guest Additions after a reboot. I later uninstalled Guest Extensions using **./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run uninstall** off the ISO. That didn't change anything. Why was I running 4.3.18 Guest Extensions? I upgraded VirtualBox right before upgrading all my guest OS's packages.

Here is all I see:[image: Unity desktop with no Unity]

Answer (score 0):

It might be a compiz issue. 
Restarting it with `DISPLAY=:0 compiz --replace` from tty1 (control-alt-f1) and then switching back to tty7 (control-alt-f7) might help.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to get to terminal that way, but running **DISPLAY=:0 compiz --replace** never returns my command prompt. Don't know if that's intentional. If I press Ctrl-Alt-F7 after waiting a while, I have the same screen with no Unity stuff.